# Solving Equation $x^2-(2+i)x+(-1+7i)=0$

Tags: calculus, quadratics

$x^2-(2+i)x+(-1+7i)=0$

I tried to solve it and I got stuck here:

$x=(2+i)±\sqrt{\frac{7-24i}{2}}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348), should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!

Comment: Check again the solution you got. There is either a typo or a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you correctly found the discriminant:
$$D =  B^2 - 4AC = [-(2+i)]^2-4(-1+7i) = 7 - 24i.$$
Then:
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-B\pm \sqrt{D}}{2A}=\frac{2+i\pm\sqrt{7-24i}}{2}.\tag{1}$$
But:
$$\sqrt{7-24i}=\pm(4-3i).$$ Why?

Let $\sqrt{7-24i} = z\implies z^2 = 7-24i$.
If we let $z = a+bi \implies a^2-b^2 +2ab i = 7-24i $. Thus:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a^2 - b^2 = 7\\
ab = -12
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Solving the above system in Reals, we get 2 pairs of solutions: $(a,b) = (4,-3)$ and $(a,b) = (-4,3)$. Both $z_1 = 4-3i$ and $z_2 = -4+3i$ satisfy the equation $z^2 = 7-24i$. No matter the choice we make for $\sqrt{27-4i}$ (either $4-3i$ or $-4+3i$), the solutions given by the quadratic formula will be the same, due to the "$\pm$ sign" in the numerator.

Apply this to $(1)$ and you will get the result.

Comment: I'd write $(4-3i)^2=7-24i$, rather than $\sqrt{7-24i}=4-3i$.

Comment: @egreg Does it make any real difference the way I defined it?

Comment: @thanasissdr Yes, it does. "$(4-3i)^2=7-24i$" is true no matter what, "$\sqrt{7-24i}=4-3i$" is mostly wrong if not meaningless.

Comment: $\sqrt{ 7-24i}$ in this context seems a valid device to reach the op level of uderstanding

Comment: @NajibIdrissi According to [Mathworld Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareRoot.html), the square root of a complex number can be evaluated as:
$$\sqrt{x+iy} =\frac12\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot\Bigg[\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}\right)+i\left(\operatorname{sgn}(y)\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}\right)\Bigg].$$ If we make the substitutions $x=7,y=-24$ we get the same result.

Comment: @thanasissdr: There is no such thing as _the_ square root of a complex number. And unlike the reals (where the square root sign denotes the unique positive square root), in the complex numbers there is no canonical way of deciding which square root to take. Having said that, it does no harm here, because each choice leads to the same pair of solutions to the quadratic equation.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, I can understand what you say, but what about the link I provided above?

Comment: @thanasissdr You conveniently didn't put in the $\pm$ sign, why is that?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I could have done so, but it has no effect to the solution, due to the $\pm$ sign in the formula, which gives the solutions of the quadratic formula. So would it be ok if I just wrote $\sqrt{7-24i} = \pm(4-3i)$ or it is not acceptable, too?

Comment: It's better, yes. The end result is the same, but the steps you take matter too. It's like dividing by zero in the middle of derivation, it doesn't matter if you get to the right result if it's through the wrong method.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

### HINT

Write $7 - 24\iota $ in the $r e^{\iota \theta}$ form, where $r = \sqrt{7^2 + 24^2}$ and $ \tan{\theta} = -\frac{24}{7} $. Note, $\theta$ will be in 4th quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

> By using factor method:

$$x^2-(2+i)x+(-1+7i)=0$$

- Rewrite the left hand side of the equation.

$$x^2-(2+i)x+(-1+7i)=(-1+7i)+(-2-i)x+x^{2}$$

- Factor the left hand side.

$$(( -3+i)+x)((1-2i)+x)=0$$
 - Solve each term in the product separately.

$(-3+i)+x=0$ or $(1-2i)+x=0$

$$x=3-i \text{ or } x=-1+2i $$

> Or we can Solve the quadratic equation by completing the square

indeed,

$$x^2-(2+i)x+(-1+7i)=0$$

Subtract $-1+7i$ from both sides:

$$x^2-(2+i)x=1-7i$$
Take one half of the coefficient of $x$ and square it, then add it to both sides

Add $\dfrac{3}{4}+i$ to both sides:

$$(\dfrac{3}{4}+i)+(-2-i)x+x^{2}=\dfrac{7}{4}-6i$$

- Factor the left hand side.

Write the left hand side as a square:

$$\left(x+(-1-\dfrac{i}{2})\right)^{2}=\dfrac{7}{4}-6i$$

- Eliminate the exponent on the left hand side.

Take the square root of both sides:

$$x+(-1-\dfrac{i}{2})=\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{4}-6i} \text{ Or } x+(-1-\dfrac{i}{2})=-\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{4}-6i}$$

add $1+\dfrac{i}{2}$ to both sides:

$$x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})+\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{4}-6i} \text{ Or } x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})-\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{4}-6i}$$

$$x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})+\sqrt{4-6i-\dfrac{9}{4}} \text{ Or } x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})-\sqrt{4-6i-\dfrac{9}{4}}$$

$$x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})+\sqrt{\dfrac{(4-3i)^{2}}{4}} \text{ Or } x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})-\sqrt{\dfrac{(4-3i)^{2}}{4}}$$

$$x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})+\dfrac{(4-3i)}{2} \text{ Or } x=(1+\dfrac{i}{2})-\dfrac{(4-3i)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Some other answers explained how to get square roots of complex numbers, but it's also worth mentioning that there is an explicit formula you can get by following such methods in generality (leaving the variables in). The formula obtained is that the square root of $a + bi$ with nonnegative real part is given by

$$\sqrt{a + bi} = \sqrt{{a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \over 2}} \pm \sqrt{{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \over 2}}\,\,i$$

You choose the $\pm$ to ensure your square root is in the correct quadrant. So in your case

$$\sqrt{7 - 24i} = \sqrt{{7 + \sqrt{625} \over 2}} \pm \sqrt{{-7 + \sqrt{625} \over 2}}\,i$$
$$= 4 \pm 3i$$
Based on $7 - 24i$'s position in the fourth quadrant, you'd choose the $-$ in the $\pm$, so you'd have
$$\sqrt{7 - 24i} = 4 - 3i$$
This is the square root with positive real part. $-4 + 3i$ is the square root with negative real part; you just multiply the other square root by $-1$. Due to the $\pm$ in the quadratic formula, it doesn't matter which square root you use when solving quadratic equations.